# Recorte de imagem em wordpress e exclusão da imagem original

Tags: wordpress, upload, imagem, funções, resize

Após o *upload* de uma imagem no *wordpress* gostaria fazer uma verificação se a imagem cadastrada é maior que o tamanho limite declarado, se for maior quero deletar a imagem original na pasta *upload* e mantem apenas as imagens recortadas com *thumbnails* (mídia).

Estou usando esta função no **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'delete_fullsize_image' );
function delete_fullsize_image( $metadata )
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit( $upload_dir['basedir'] ) . $metadata['file'];
    $deleted = unlink( $full_image_path );

    return $metadata;
}
```

Exemplo:

Eu especifiquei que o tamanho maximo das imagens sera de 300x300, ao enviar uma imagem de 350x350 ele recorta a imagem para o tamanho de 300x300 e exclui a imagem original de 350x350.

Como é possivel fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplique no arquivo **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'delete_fullsize_image' );
function delete_fullsize_image( $metadata )
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit( $upload_dir['basedir'] ) . $metadata['file'];
    if($metadata['width'] >= '300'){
     $deleted = unlink( $full_image_path );
    }    
    return $metadata;
}
```

Com essa função você consegue chegar a largura da imagem antes do *upload*. Nesse caso o valor limite é de 300.

Answer (score 1):

O `PHP` tem um método chamado [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) que, como o nome diz, retorna o tamanho da imagem. Por exemplo

```
$filepath = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c2/Peter_Griffin.png';

$size = getimagesize($filepath);

var_dump($size);
```

retorna

```
array(6) { [0]=> int(247) [1]=> int(359) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> string(24) "width="247" height="359"" ["bits"]=> int(8) ["mime"]=> string(9) "image/png" }
```

As duas primeiras posições desse array representam, respectivamente, o comprimento e a altura da sua imagem. Com isso, basta fazer uma comparação antes de deletar a imagem. Seu código fica

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'delete_fullsize_image' );
function delete_fullsize_image( $metadata ){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $full_image_path = trailingslashit( $upload_dir['basedir'] ) . $metadata['file'];
    $size = getimagesize($full_image_path);

    if(($full_image_path[0] < 300) and ($full_image_path[1] < 300)){
        $deleted = unlink( $full_image_path );
    }

    return $metadata;
}
```